# Should I use "ascent" or "ascension" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> With little remaining energy, Mary hauled herself into elevator,
>   fought the gravity generated by the **ascent/ascension**, and staggered
>   out to the 14th floor.

Which word should I use? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your usage

> With little remaining energy, Mary hauled herself into elevator, fought the gravity generated by the **ascent**, and staggered out to the 14th floor.

Since Mary is climbing upwards, her action is called an

> **ascent** - (*n*) a climb or walk to the summit of a mountain or hill.

in mountaineering first attempts of climbing a mountain are called

> [first ascents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_first_ascents)

It should be pointed out that your sentence does not really make sense since climbing upwards does not *generate gravity*.

Your other word has a very different meaning

> **ascension** - (*n*) the act of rising to an important position or a higher level
>
> June 2nd will be the 64th anniversary of Queen Elizabeth's **ascension** to the throne.

One of the most famous paintings of an ascension is  **Raphael's** *Transfiguration*

[image]

This painting is also the subject of one of the [largest "instant" Poloroids ever](http://archives.chicagotribune.com/1979/12/02/page/190/article/photography)

Comment: When you take an elevator the gravity increases (you feel more heavy). Or you think that wasn't the way of wording it?

Comment: I think it depends if the elevator is going up or down... :)  The increased weight you feel is your own inertia relative to the elevator moving but, if the elevator is going up, at the top, you will actually **weigh less** than at the bottom. A person who weighs 150 pounds on the surface of the earth would weigh approximately 149.92 pounds at **10,000 feet above sea level**.

Comment: Wait, so why do you feel lighter when the elevator is going down? And heavier when the elevator is going up? Am I wrong? I'm going to take the elevator later just to test this.

Comment: You will feel heavier/lighter when the elevator's acceleration is greater than your body's, you will probably need to travel over several floors, 10-20, to get the effect, and you will need a fast elevator. Most elevators are programmed not to move so quickly so the riders will not feel motion sickness. If you are in a high rise, your ears will also "pop" around the 20th floor during the **ascent** to the top.

Answer (score 2):

*Ascent* and *ascension* are similar words, certainly, but the meaning is not the same:

> ***ascent*** (n) : the act of rising or mounting upward, an advance in social status or reputation
>
> ***ascension*** (n): the act of rising or ascending; especially : the act of moving to a higher or more powerful position

In your example it would be better to use *ascent* since that conveys only that Mary is moving upwards.  Meanwhile, *ascension*, without any further context, implies that she is *ascending* toward Heaven, since that is a context in which the word is commonly used.